# Accessing a table in an Oracle Schema with Pandas

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I have an Oracle Schema called "L_US" and a table called "entity". How do I store the contents of the "entity" table in a dataframe ? I tried:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn('URL', '1521', 'SERVICE_NAME')
dsnStr = dsnStr.replace('SID', 'SERVICE_NAME')
connect_str = 'oracle://user:password@"+dsnStr'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_str)
df = pd.read_sql_table("L_US.entity", engine)
```

However, I get an error that the table is not found.

Comment: Hard to say as we know nothing about 'engine'. How do you connect to database ? Are you sure that the user you use for authentification has access to the table L_US.entity ?

Comment: added the entire snippet of the code. i have access to the L_US schema. Just need to access the table

Comment: [In Oracle, users and schemas are essentially the same thing.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37022). If connection worked for that user, try simply reading in *entity*.